# What is the easiest way to get up to a floating island?

Tags: terraria

I know where one of my floating islands is, but the eater of souls knock me off of my tower. What is the easiest way to get up to it?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and safest way in your current state (I think you are not in the hardmode) is to use a [Gravitation Potion](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gravitation_Potion), which can be easily found in pots or chests at the underground level. You may have got one by now with all the mining you did or you can craft it with some ingredients, but I don't think you got a [feather](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Feather) at this stage into the game

Comment: Agree with it being the easiest (and by far the quickest) method. It's also a good way to localize the Floating Islands. It's even better with a [**Lucky Horseshoe**](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lucky_Horseshoe) to make sure you won't take fall damage.

Comment: If you have some luck, you can get that Horseshoe right on the Floating Island you were searching for. I consider the Horseshoe one of the most useful items before you acquire Wings .

Comment: Ah, that's true it's in Floating Islands' chests, so if it's your first time you won't have one. If you got an [**Umbrella**](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Umbrella) from the Surface chests though, you can use it instead. Otherwise, one has just to be careful not to be too high during the landing. ;) (I don't like the Featherfall potion as it makes you slow, so you have to use much more Gravitation Potion and at this stage you don't have plenty of them...)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way in early game to climb up and down fast is using **ropes**. You can buy them from the merchant for **10 copper** each, or find them by smashing pots in the caves.  It goes without saying that this item is very common and very useful until you gain access to movement-based accessories (boots, wings, etc...)

You can also place blocks around the ropes, so the eaters of souls can't cross them, and you'll be safe going up and down with the rope.

But the safest, (and most expensive) way to get up is to use teleporters. They are only accessible in hardmode though, but once placed and wired up, they will transport you in your island in a blink of an eye.

Answer (score 0):

I guess easiest is subjective -- because to me, the easiest would be using only materials I have already and doesn't require going and getting anything else -- ie "nerdpole" up to the top. Just jump and put a block under you, and repeat that until you get to the floating island. Granted the way down becomes much more complicated, but it does allow getting up relatively quickly.

Aside from that, I've used a slightly different technique that actually creates jumpable "steps" with the dirt blocks that I can jump up to, then later run down without taking injury. It may be slower than using ropes, but if you don't have ropes already (or can't make them) you can get plenty of dirt blocks.